# Add thumbnails to product description area of Magento that show in Main image box when clicked

Tags: magento

I would like to add thumbnails to my product description area in Magento that when clicked show as a large size in the main image box. The same as what is happening on this page with the different colour options: http://www.weddingstar.com.au/product/love-bird-damask-nut-free-gourmet-milk-chocolate-bar

Any ideas on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could take the elements of media.phtml and put it in the description.phtml file. There is a better way to do it but thats a quick and relatively easy way to get it done and polish later. hopefully thats a nudge in the right direction.